# Saving/Retrieving Binary data from database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat

I have a web app deployed in tomcat 6.0.32 x64 and it's using Hibernate 3.0 to connect a Postgres 9.0 x64 database.

The app saves a binary field in the database and when I find it, it is different.

Binary Saved:
[-82, 120, 71, 23, -88, 67, 36, 30, 57, -72, 42, 29, -64, 93, -8, -103, -63, 124, 66, 20]

Binary Obtained:
[-67, 55, 56, 52, 55, 49, 55, 97, 56, 52, 51, 50, 52, 49, 101, 51, 57, 98, 56, 50, 97, 49, 100, 99, 48, 53, 100, 102, 56, 57, 57, 99, 49, 55, 99, 52, 50, 49, 52]

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details about how the data is stored. But it's peculiar you are getting twice as many bytes back as saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your postgres jdbc driver version.  It should be at least as recent as your DB server, so you need a 9.0 driver or better.

I believe the bytea wire format changed in 9.0, which could explain this problem if you have an old driver.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was used a jdbc 8.3, when I changed it for jdbc 9.0 It's works great.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough details, but i'm going to go out on a limb and guess that at some point you are translating bytes to characters (your output looks about twice as long as your input, java characters are 2 bytes).  bytes != chars.

otherwise, it could be something related to incorrect usage of streams.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use always a bytes array, I don't translate the data. I think that the problem maybe is related to Java x64 in Windows

Comment: I find that highly unlikely. Realize that BLOBS and CLOBS kinda suck in Hibernate. Not completely it's fault - but the different DB servers have so many issues with different implementations, that a world of hurt ensues.