# byte[] messed up in database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a SWT/Hibernate/Postgresql application, and I want to add an image in my database as a byte[] and display it.

Here the relevant code to load the image in a bean. AFAIK, it works correctly.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
long length = file.length();
if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    is.close();
    return false;
}
byte[] image = new byte[(int)length];
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < image.length && (numRead=is.read(image, offset, image.length-offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
}
if (offset < image.length) {
    result = false;
}
is.close();
```

Then I simply set my byte[] image in a bean, with such a hibernate setup (legacy hbm.xml):

```
<property name="image" type="byte[]"/>
```

and such a database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
(
  ...
  image bytea,
  ...
)
```

When I create the record in database (which works) and immediately use the code to display the image in my SWT application (so the byte array was really created by above piece of code), it works ok and displays the image. But when I run my application and just retrieve the record from my database, the image is unreadable. I logged the content of the byte array on creation and after database retrieval, and they are not at all the same. What could be the reason?

Comment: Well, i had looked in SO for similar questions but had not seen this one: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602111/saving-retrieving-binary-data-from-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid. Just for the record, it's just that I used a driver for pg 8.4 and a pg 9.1 database...